# linux terminal, see the output one page at a time

Tags: linux, scrolling

I am running a make file and when it runs it prints a whole bunch of log with errors and warnings. Please let me know how will I be able to see the output one page at a time. Or after the make file is run, how will I be able to scroll up and scroll down. I am using secure CRT to log on to Linux from a windows machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before running `make`, pipe its STDOUT into a viewer, like `less`.

```
make | less
```

Then, you can skip through pages with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Alternatively, write the output to a file and read it later:

```
make > make.out
less make.out
```

Quit `less` with <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: To capture stderr as well as stdout, use this when you pipe: `make 2>&1 | less`; and this when you output to a file: `make > make.out 2>&1`.

Comment: This is not working for me. Kind of strange.

Answer (score 3):

It is often useful to capture both `stdout` and `stderr`, so something like this would work:

```
make > make.log 2> make.err
```

`stdout` is saved in `make.log` and `stderr` is saved in `make.err`.

Comment: I'd change that to `make 2>&1 | tee make.log`. This way you still see the progress on the screen, and have the errors shown in the right place (single log file).

Comment: @Izzy, depending on what comes out of make, you might get the output from the two streams mixed incoherently. As for following the progress, run `tail -f` in another terminal: `tail -f make.log make.err`.

Comment: Okay, then simply take my suggestion as an "alternative" instead of a "replacement". Guess both have their advantages, depending on your goals and habits ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use |more
For example lshw | more